# Regex for Strings without Consecutive Letters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given an array of words, I want to find all letters that don't appear consecutively (e.g., ee, aa, ZZ, TT) in any of the words.

I have tried a variety of approaches and am hitting a roadblock in my understanding. This should be with vanilla JavaScript ES6 (no libraries or imports).

Here is a short sample word list I'm using to test:

```
const sampleArr = [
 "BORROW", "BRANCH", "CYST", "DEIFIED", "DIPLOMATIC",
 "GEESE", "HAIRCUT", "HYMN", "LEVEL", "MOSQUITO",
 "MURDRUM", "NON", "POP", "POWER", "GOD", "THY"
]
```

And here is the code I came up with, but it is only returning me the matches, but I need inverse/reverse matches.

So, if there are no occurrences of "AA" for instance, the code should add "A" to the return array.

I've tried negative lookahead regex, but couldn't get it to work right.

Here is the code I currently have that gives no errors, but doesn't work right:

```js
wordlist = sampleArr

let joinedWordList = wordlist.join('')

console.log(joinedWordList)

let pattern = /([A-Z])\1+/g

doubleLettersFound = joinedWordList.match(pattern)

let singleDoubleLettersFound = doubleLettersFound.filter(el => el.split('')[0]
  // console.log(el)
)

console.log(singleDoubleLettersFound)
```

This is the result I'm receiving:

```
[ 'RR', 'MM', 'DD', 'EE', 'PP' ]
```

Also, if it helps, here is an earlier regex (in context) I was trying:

```
  // Join word as string then process; For each letter, if consecutives found anywhere,
  //  go to next letter; If no consecutives found, add letter to out.lettersNoConsec
  haystack = arr.join('')
  out.lettersNonConsec = abc.split('').filter(ltr => haystack.match(RegExp(`(${ltr})\\1`)))
  // console.log(letters
```

Comment: What should be the output array ?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern with a back reference is definitely a good idea to identify letters that repeat consecutively, but:

- As some letters might not occur at all in any of the strings, you cannot only rely on the strings themselves; you need to iterate all the letters of the alphabet -- which is what you seemed to try in the second attempt.
- If you join all words together, you should leave a space or some other punctuation between words as otherwise you may get false matches: the last letter of a word might be the same as the first letter of the next word
- If you change the regex to have a look-ahead for the second character, it will match only the first character of a repeated sequence of a letter. That single letter will make it easier to work with.

Here is a possible solution:

```js
const sampleArr = [
 "BORROW", "BRANCH", "CYST", "DEIFIED", "DIPLOMATIC",
 "GEESE", "HAIRCUT", "HYMN", "LEVEL", "MOSQUITO",
 "MURDRUM", "NON", "POP", "POWER", "GOD", "THY"
];

const allwords = sampleArr.join(" ").toUpperCase();
const paired = new Set(allwords.match(/([A-Z])(?=\1)/g));
const result = [..."ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"]
    .filter(ch => !paired.has(ch));
    
console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a good approach. I'm looking forward to trying it out. Can you explain what the `Set` and `has` do? I'm still learning the 2015+ array methods.

Comment: See documentation of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). It is used here to turn an array of characters to a set of characters. A set has the advantage that it has no duplicates (those will be ignored), and that testing membership is more efficient in a set (using [`.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has)) than in an array (using [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)).